# Passing an instance variable as an argument for a function in a class

Tags: python, class, variables, instance, self

I have the following problem in Python:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.variable = number

    def function(self, argument=(self.variable)):
        some_code()
```

It gives me the following error:

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

I need the instance variable to act as the default value of the argument in the function. Am I doing it right in passing the instance variable like that or am I missing something?

Comment: @NayantaraJeyaraj Indentation in Python matters. If you remove the indentation, you will get an error saying "IndentationError: unexpected indent", which is clearly not relevant to this question.